How to Optimize Bulk Insertion in MongoDB for Event Schedules Without Nested Loops?
I'm developing a Node.js application that requires adding event schedules into a MongoDB database. Currently, my implementation utilizes nested loops to create these event entries, which may lead to performance issues when handling large datasets.
Here I want to skip the iteration part from this code.
as you can see there this code can lead us to undefinate number of itertaion first which can make this process slower. So is there any way by which we can limit or remove this iteration part
exports.addEventSchedules = async (req) => {
  const {
    eventIdentifier,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    isSameDayFlag,
    selectedDaysArray,
  } = req.body;

  const eventScheduleArray = [
    {
      eventStartDate: "2024-02-29T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventEndDate: "2024-03-01T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventStartDay: "Friday",
      eventEndDay: "Saturday",
    },
    {
      eventStartDate: "2024-03-03T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventEndDate: "2024-03-04T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventStartDay: "Monday",
      eventEndDay: "Tuesday",
    },
    {
      eventStartDate: "2024-03-07T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventEndDate: "2024-03-08T18:30:00.000Z",
      eventStartDay: "Friday",
      eventEndDay: "Saturday",
    },
  ];

  const eventDataList = await fetchEventsByIdentifier({
    eventIdentifier,
  });

  const eventScheduleDocuments = eventDataList.flatMap(
    (eventData) => {
      const eventID = eventData.id;
      const eventSegmentID = eventData.segmentId;

      return eventScheduleArray.map((eventScheduleEntry) => ({
        eventId: eventID,
        segmentId: eventSegmentID,
        eventStartDate: eventScheduleEntry.eventStartDate,
        eventEndDate: eventScheduleEntry.eventEndDate,
        eventStartDay: eventScheduleEntry.eventStartDay,
        eventEndDay: eventScheduleEntry.eventEndDay,
      }));
    },
  );

  return insertEventSchedules(eventScheduleDocuments);
};

The current approach utilizes nested loops to create event schedule entries. This may not be efficient, especially when processing a large number of events and dates. I'm seeking a way to optimize this process, particularly by leveraging MongoDB's bulk operations to reduce the number of individual insertions.
Question

How can I refactor this code to effectively use MongoDB's bulk write operations?
What is the best way to avoid nested loops while ensuring that all event schedule entries are created and saved correctly?
Are there any best practices for structuring data for bulk insertions in MongoDB that I should consider?

I just dont want to use the loop and my data will llokk like
{
EventId: eventId
"eventStartDate": "2024-03-07T18:30:00.000Z",
"eventEndDate": "2024-03-08T18:30:00.000Z",
"eventStartDay": "Friday",
"eventEndDay": "Saturday"
}

"may lead to performance issues when handling large datasets"? What kind of performance issues are you seeing – or is this hypothetical? Either way, I'd use generator functions to generate the documents and e.g. bulk-write in batches of e.g. 1000 documents or whatever.

yes this hypothetical currently. But I want to skip the iteration part from this code.
as you can see there this code can lead us to undefinate number of itertaion first which can make this process slower. So is there any way by which we can limit or remove this iteration part

Are schedules stored in mongodb too?

If you have data to iterate over, and you want to put it in the database as is, there's not much you can do but to iterate and put it there...

No we will genarte the schedule arry for the use. Or can we use a approach where we can xonvert one them to object and then proceed with the updateMany or insertMany  Opertation. I think that should work
